# How was the etymology of "hormigón" established?

Tags: etimología, dle, latín

In [this map](https://i.redd.it/bktbhesor1901.png) linked by [this r/europe post](https://www.reddit.com/r/europe/comments/7pdo35/the_influence_of_france_is_strong/), it is claimed that Spanish *hormigón* might be derived either *«from Latin* formicare *(mold), or perhaps from Spanish* hormigo *»* (gruel, though also a kind of cake).

However, the DLE definition only mentions the Spanish origin, nothing about Latin:

> **[hormigón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KeqZ0FM)**.
>   De *hormigo* 'gachas de harina'.
>
> 1. m. Material que resulta de la mezcla de agua, arena, grava y cemento o cal, y que, al fraguar, adquiere más resistencia.

And [*hormigo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KeqHrCZ) itself is listed as derived from Spanish [*hormiga*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Kelws9T), which is in turn derived from Latin *[formīca](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/formica#Latin)* which means "ant".

My question is: **how did the RAE come up with the current origin? Why did they dismiss the possible Latin root?**
Or is the above map just wrong in its claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think DLE editors chose the most probable etymology and discarded the less probable, at least at the moment when the entry was last edited. Maybe there is new evidence and the entry should be updated, but in the 1980s the situation was as follows.

On one side, there was this sort of oatmeal called [**hormigos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KeqHrCZ), also a dessert with crushed nuts, whose name *maybe* comes from the resemblance of its small solid pieces with ants. Theory says [**hormigón**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KeqZ0FM|KevGmFd) takes its name from its similitude to this food.

Also, there is an obscure synonym of both *hormigos* and *hormigón*, [**nuégado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QhkZE1i), which shows the same relationship.

This is the most plausible theory.

On the other hand, there is the Latin noun *forma*, meaning 'framework' (the wooden frame inside of which you pour concrete or mud and let it harden, to create a slab). A verb *formĭcare*, meaning "to build using this kind of framework", *could* have derived from it. Then, it became Spanish **hormegón*, and from there *hormigón*, by "contamination" of *hormiga*.

The problem with this theory is that there are no traces of this theoretical verb *formĭcare*, except *only* in a French work from the 11th century where it is used as a synonym of *formare*. There is no other testimony or descendant words in Romance languages.

This is the least plausible theory, for lack of evidence.

But maybe now (2018) there is new evidence for the second theory, although I doubt it.

---

Source: Corominas y Pascual. Diccionario Etimológico.

Answer (score 2):

Etimologías de Chile apunta en la [etimología de `hormigón`](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?hormigo.n) que el origen de esta palabra

> ha intentado explicarse a través de **dos posiciones inconciliables**.

La primera sería a través de la familia léxica de "forma" y la otra a través de "hormiga".

Wikipedia también recoge que hormigón viene

> del latín formicō, «moldeado, conformado»

Aunque no aporta cita para apoyarlo.

Etimologías de Chile aporta en la entrada anteriormente citada que la propuesta de "hormiga" es la recogida por el DRAE, sugiriendo, como indicas, que `hormigón` llegó desde `hormiga` a través de "hormigo" porque en los plurales de esta palabra

> designa preparados que pueden conectarse semánticamente entre sí por tratarse de mezclas de fluidos y sólidos menudos [...] especialmente si alguno de estos se destaca entre los restantes por un mayor tamaño de los granos o partículas.

La explicación que da tras esta definición es que los granos de esta mezcla (el hormigón) recordarían a hormigas (!), lo que explica la relación con dicha palabra.

Esta entrada de Etimologías de Chile recoge una opinión personal de alguien que dice que ese "doble origen" puede reconciliarse en uno solo.

Para responder a la pregunta, parece que la RAE no ignoró el origen latino, pero ese `De hormigo 'gachas de harina'.`  conduce a error ya que "hormigo" es una "mezcla de fluidos y sólidos menudos", que también son las gachas. Supongo que la entrada debería decir `De hormigo 'mezcla de fluidos y sólidos menudos'.` y es esa "aclaración" de la etimología lo que está mal explicado. El mapa que planteas no parece ser incorrecto, lo he contrastado con otras fuentes.